# Calculate the position of the camera using the two reference points

Tags: opencv, math, geometry

I am trying to find the position of the camera in (x,y,z). R1 and R2 are the two reference points on the floor. R1' and R2' are the points shown in a image plane. 2492 pixels is the width of the viewing  I was able to find the distance between R1 and R2 (0.98m), also between R1' and R2' (895.9pixels). The angle at which the camera is 69 degrees. The camera is placed on the left side of the reference points.

I am trying to do a mathematical model. If anyone could please help me with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to draw a simple sketch explaining your problem? It would help a lot.

Comment: did you calibrate you camera, if not ? deal with that first. and the take search about laser triangulation it may help ou find out how to do it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3pf2man7ermdwiw/dOhTFBnSpL

here is the link of the image. hope it helps...

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Processing, the programming language, or were you referring to "image processing"? In which case you need to remove the `processing` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem, as you described it, is too ambiguous to be solved.

Your problem is quite similar to the general PnP problem, whose objective is to estimate the relative pose between an object and a camera, based on a set of N known 3D points and their projections in the image. From what I know, the P3P problem, i.e. the PnP problem for 4 3D points and their 4 projections (see [this website](http://iplimage.com/blog/p3p-perspective-point-overview/) for a description), is the best we can solve. FYI, OpenCV implements the `solvePnP` function, which does that for N>=4.

Comparatively, in your problem, you do know the viewing angle of the camera, but you only have the distance between 2 3D points and the distance between their 2 projections. I do not think this can be solved as is. However, there may be a way if you look for hidden additional constraints (e.g. the camera center and 2 3D points are coplanar, etc) or if you intentionally add some (e.g. use more points).